# Как посчитать количество строк файла, в которых количество слов четное?

Tags: java, алгоритм, строки

Нужно посчитать кол-во строк из файла, в которых кол-во слов - четное. Сделал так:

```
 public class got {
     public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
         String line;
         BufferedReader input = null;
         PrintWriter out = null;
         int count = 0;
         try {
             input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("filea.txt")); // задаем источник
             out = new PrintWriter("filea_copy.txt"); // задаем приемник
             while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {

                 StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(line, "\n");
                 while (st.hasMoreTokens())
                     if ((st.nextToken().split("\\s+").length & 1) == 0) count++;

             }
             System.out.println("Найдено " + count + "  строк");

         } catch (Exception e) {
             System.out.println("error");
         } finally {
             if (input != null) {
                 input.close();
             }
             if (out != null) {
                 out.close();
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

После чего я был послан переделывать, мол если бы я думал головой, выражения

```
 (st.nextToken().split("\\s+").length&1)==0) count++;
```

бы не возникло. Посему два вопроса:

1. `nextToken()` возвращает мне строку из файла, т.к. в `StringTokenizer(line,"\n")` стоит соответствующий делиметр - можно ли так утверждать или нет?
2. Как реализовать с помощью `countTokens()`?

Не могу понять, как его применить на строку из файла, тупо бегает по одной и той же строчке, соответственно бесконечно увеличивая каунтер, если это сделано вот так:

```
while (st.hasMoreTokens) {
    if (st.countTokens() & 1==0)
        count++;
}
```

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: @fiesko769and, Пожалуйста, оформляйте вопросы согласно правилам сообщества, иначе они будут удаляться.

Answer (score 1):

Вы уже читаете файл построчно, поэтому конструкция `StringTokenizer st=new StringTokenizer(line,"\n")` не имеет смысла. Логично было бы создать токенайзер, который делил бы прочитанную строку по словам и вызвать у него метод `countTokens()`.

Comment: Не могли бы вы показать, как это делается?

Comment: StringTokenizer st=new StringTokenizer(line,"\n,. ");
while(st.hasMoreTokens())
if(st.countTokens()%2==0)count++;

Тупо читает одну и ту же строку из файла, и не выбирается из нее. Что делаю не так?

Comment: @fiesko769and Зачем вам здесь цикл? Достаточно проверки по кол-ву токенов. Прочитайте документацию по StringTokenizer и упомянутым методам и вам все станет ясно.